# Possible to transfer state/props data from server

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to transfer state from server to client? I know I can simply request the initial data again on the client, but that involves extra requests. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: If you're on rails platform the react-rails gem 1.0.0 pre version will do this via the prerender: true option https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#view-helper-1 however understandably you may not be on rails

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer initial data from your server as follow:

```
<script>
    var data = <json data serialized by your server language>;
</script>
```

Then, using `data` variable you can initialize your components' `state` and `props`.